# How to validate dynamically generated fields with bootstrap validator. `Error Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Tags: bootstrapvalidator

I have my form here that contains the fields that i want validated. Currently there is one `Name of Recipient` field but the user can click the `addKit` button which will dynamically generate new input fields for the user to fill out. The validation library i am using validates the fields by matching the `input` field `name` to the `bootstrapValidator` `fields` list. In this case for instance, it will look at `<input type="text" style="margin:0px 0px 7.5px 0px;" class="form-control" name="kits[COZ1][1][name]" value="">` and match the name `kits[COZ1][1][name]` to the field name in the fields list in the javascript. Now as there are more inputs generated the name will change dynamically, the next input name will be `kits[COZ1][2][name]` and so on... I am using the `addField` method to add the field dynamically but run into an error. What am i doing wrong here?

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="" method="post"  id="order">
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Requestor</b></legend>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Requestor Name</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="requestorName" placeholder="Requestor Name" class="form-control" id="requestorName" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Requestor Email</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input  name="requestorEmail" placeholder="Requestor Email" class="form-control" id="requestorEmail" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Requestor Broker Dealer</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input  name="firm" placeholder="Firm Name" class="form-control" id="firm" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<legend><b>Kit Details</b></legend>

<?php foreach($kit_types as $type => $description): ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><?php echo $description; ?></label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" size="10" value="1" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity_<?php echo $type; ?>" id="quantity_<?php echo $type; ?>" type="text" required />
      </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please enter the Quantity of Kits Needed
        </div>
      <button style="margin:15px 15px 0px 0px;" class="kitQuantityUpdate btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="update_<?php echo $type; ?>" type="button" value="Show" />Show <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
      <button style="margin:15px 15px 0px 0px;" class="kitAdd btn btn-warning btn-sm"  id="add_<?php echo $type; ?>" type="button" value="Add Kit" />Add Kit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button>

    </div>
    <div class="kitDetail" id="kitDetail_<?php echo $type; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name of Recipient</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div id="kitList">
        <div class="detailList" id="detail_<?php echo $type; ?>">
          <input type="text" style="margin:0px 0px 7.5px 0px;" class="form-control" name="kits[COZ1][1][name]" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></div>
</div>

                            <?php endforeach; ?>
<!--<legend><b>Kit Delivery</b></legend>-->

<div class="form-group" style="visibility: hidden">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Delivery Method</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
            <select id="mailtype" name="mailtype" class="form-control selectpicker" >
                <option value="Email" selected>Email</option>
          <!--  <option value="Hard Copy">Hard Copy</option>
                <option value="Hard Copy & Email">Hard Copy & Email</option>-->
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for placing your Order, we will contact you shortly.</div>

<button  id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit Order <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
    <!--<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Order" />-->
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I have a my validation rules set.

```
    $('#order').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },

    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
      $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...


      var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');
      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
        $('#order').bootstrapValidator("resetForm",true);
        console.log(result);
      }, 'json');
    },
    excluded: [':disabled'],

    fields: {
      kits[COZ1][1][name]: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply recipient name'
          }
        }
      },
      requestorName: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your name'
          }
        }
      },
      requestorEmail: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your email address'
          },
          emailAddress: {
            message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
          }
        }
      },
      firm: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 3,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your Broker Dealer'
          }
        }
      },
      /*
      address1: {
      validators: {
      stringLength: {
      min: 8,
    },
    notEmpty: {
    message: 'Please supply recipient street address'
  }
  }
  },
  address2: {
  validators: {
    stringLength: {
      min: 8,
    },
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'Please supply your street address'
    }
  }
  },
  city: {
  validators: {
    stringLength: {
      min: 4,
    },
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'Please supply recipient city'
    }
  }
  },
  state: {
  validators: {
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'Please select recipient state'
    }
  }
  },
  zip: {
  validators: {
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'Please supply recipient zip code'
    },
    zipCode: {
      country: 'US',
      message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
    }
  }
  },
  phone: {
  validators: {
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'Please supply recipient phone number'
    },
    phone: {
      country: 'US',
      message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
    }
  }
  },

  ship_email: {
  validators: {
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'Please supply recipient address'
    },
    emailAddress: {
      message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
    }
  }
  },
  */
  }

  }).on('click', '.kitAdd',function() {
    var data = kitAdd($(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]);
    console.log(data);
    var prefix = data[0];
    var suffix = data[1];
    var type = data[2];

    var template = $("#detail_"+type);
    var clone = template.clone();
    clone.attr('id', "detail_"+type);
    // clone.insertBefore(template);
    var option = clone.find('input');
    var name = prefix + "[name]";
    option.attr('name', prefix + "[name]");
    var obj = clone.find('[name="'+suffix+'[name]"]')
    $("form#order").bootstrapValidator("addField", obj);
  });
```

kitAdd function simply returns data needed for input name.